# "Система друзей непоправимо улучшена"

Tags: семантика

***Система друзей непоправимо улучшена.***

Очередной шедевр копирайтеров. На сей раз - от мэйлру.
Вопрос: а есть ли тут более подходящее слово с тем же смыслом? 
Нужен синоним или, наоборот, антоним со значением "невозможно испортить" или близким.

Comment: Необратимо? По крайней мере, сохраняется комический оттенок.

Comment: Да хотелось бы что-то более активное, обращать - это, во-первых, в обе стороны можно, а во-вторых, не обязательно участие человека.

Comment: "Беспредельно", "окончательно и бесповоротно", "победоносно", "триумфальным образом", "всерьёз и надолго".

Comment: "безнадёжно улучшена"

Comment: Если в "гомеопатическом" смысле нужно, то "летально", "фатально" или "катастрофически".

Comment: @Alex_ander,  я надеялся найти что-то типа литературного эквивалента к "неиспорчиваемо".

Comment: Тогда что-нибудь экзотичное: неопалимо, нерастлимо/нерастлеваемо (от "нерастленно")...

Answer (score 1):

Если это о компьютерной системе, то это не шедевр копирайтеров, это внутренний сленг отдельных проектов.

https://sites.google.com/site/trytolearnru/raznoe/slovar-it-snika

Словарь "айтишника":

Код добра – программный код, очевидно содержащий **непоправимые улучшения.**

**Непоправимо улучшить** – запилить(сделать) годное, но не до конца проверенное изменение функционала. **Синоним — необратимо улучшить.**

Мясной коммит (ковровый коммит) – правка, судя по количеству и характеру 
изменений, наверняка содержащая **непоправимые улучшения.**

В любом сленге значение принимает какой-то переносный, часто ироничный смысл,  чтобы заменить слово каким-то  синонимом, нужно этот смысл уловить, а я, честно говоря, никак не уловлю, что значит "не до конца проверенное изменение".

Если же говорить о прямом значении, то прямой синоним - необратимое; синонимом может быть  и слово **УСТОЙЧИВОЕ улучшение**

По крайней мере, **необратимое улучшение** = устойчивое используется в научном стиле, может, это термин? Вот, например:

http://www.groont.ru/electro/safetyfactor/6.html  Необратимое улучшение строительных свойств глинистых грунтов. Электрохимическая обработка приводит к образованию в грунтах агрегатов за счет коагуляции.
Химический состав со временем после окончания электрохимической обработки остается практически неизменным, следовательно, достигается устойчивое улучшение свойств грунта. В результате электрохимической обработки достигается необратимое улучшение строительных свойств глинистых грунтов.

Comment: насчет словаря айтишника. Не принимайте эти шутки ил Лурка близко к сердцу. Я сам лет еще десять-пятнадцать назад подобные вещи писал в порядке поржать. Обычно эти идиомы мало кому известны, помимо автора "словаря". Да и контекст не предполагает, что читающий знает такие тонкости. Это массова реклама на портале, в "Моем Мире" (это иейловуая социальная сеть). . .

Comment: Необратимое - да, единственное, что вспоминают, но все-таки не совсем то. Обратить можно в обе стороны, а поправить - однозначно - улучшить. Я ищу что-то типа "неиспорчиваемо".

Answer (score 0):

Система друзей кощунственно улучшена. Система друзей в хлам улучшена.

Answer (score 0):

Беспроигрышно или безошибочно,но если с юмором – безнадёжно.

Answer (score -1):

Система друзей

> кардинально улучшена
>
> наконец-то улучшена окончательно и бесповоротно
>
> претерпела ряд фундаментальных изменений